# Require ForceTouch iOS App

Tags: ios, ios9

Is there a way to write an app's "Required device capabilities" such that the app runs only iPhone 6s and above (due to a requirement of force touch)?

Comment: Probably not. It's far better to support features that are on newest devices, but still have an app the works on other devices with the same OS version.

Comment: I don't see a reason for down-voting. There might as well be an app that makes such clever use of Force Touch that it would not be possible to implement it on older devices, such as a game.

Comment: @fabian789 I agree. This seems like something Apple has not thought through sufficiently, which is hardly the OP's fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally use the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key, which can require certain features to be present. However at this time it doesn't seem like 3D Touch has been added.

A large warning will have to suffice for now, while waiting for apple to add 3D touch as a thing you can require. Otherwise there might be some features only the new iPhones models have, such as the arm chip, you could require. I haven't looked into this though.

On apples page for documentation you can see available keys for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, where 3D Touch doesn't seem to be present.
open https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3

Comment: What about specifying the amount of RAM in the device? iPhone 6s has 2gb, and iPhone 6 only had 1gb.

Comment: On the page i linked there is a section which says:
_This key is supported in iOS 9.0 and later for devices that support 3D Touch._

Maybe requiring one of those would do it?

Comment: But isn't that for the quick action items?

Comment: I agree with the answer. You can tackle this problem like [Cycloramic did](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cycloramic-for-iphone-5-5s/id907159478). For them required feature was an iPhone shape (specific per model). On the downside, they had a ton of bad reviews from the users downloading the wrong app for their device.

Comment: @Froziph that means a device with 3d touch running ios9 will make use of the key. For other devices and oses, the key will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

No, at this time it is not possible.

It is likely that Apple will introduce a new value to use with the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.

Until that time, the best you can do is require one of (arm64, metal or opengles-3), and one of something like telephony or sms (until iPads get 3D Touch). This will at least restrict your app to the iPhone 5S and up.

And put a notice in the app description that your device requires 3D Touch.

Keep an eye on this document for all the possible device capability values:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Also, this is handy:
http://28byteslater.com/ios-compatibility/?exclude=&require=22,7,19,26#chart