# AppStore - iPhone 6S or iPad Pro or ForceTouch device only

Tags: ios, app-store, force-touch

Is it possible to limit by specific device model and type for an app on the app store?

Note: this is an App Store question and not an XCode question, so [the alleged duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810278/require-forcetouch-ios-app) does not seem relevant.

Comment: This isn't an Xcode question but actually an App Store question. Please remove duplicate flag.

Comment: The App Store is not programming related and so is off-topic for StackOverflow. It would be pointless to reopen this question only to close it again.

Comment: I disagree with app store related questions not belonging on StackOverflow, as it is directly related to development, and sometimes it is not clear where a certain effect can be achieved.